# Prolog: succ(X,Y) evade arguments are not sufficiently instantiated error?

Tags: prolog

I have a program looking like this minimal example:

```
test(1, N, M) :-
    succ(N, NN), 
    random(1, 4, X),
    test(X, NN, M).
test(2, N, M) :-
    succ(MM, M),
    random(1, 4, X),
    test(X,N, MM).
test(3, N, M) :-
    N=M.
```

My aim now is to calculate the variable `M`, such that the call:

```
test(1,1,M).
```

makes sense in this context. I know in this example I could easily replace

```
test(2, N, M) :-
    succ(MM, M),
    random(1, 4, X),
    test(X,N, MM).
```

by

```
test(2, N, M) :-
    succ(N, NN),
    random(1, 4, X),
    test(X,NN, M).
```

to solve the problem. But in my more complicated program this is not possible. And I don't have the clue to replace this example by another one to exclude this possibility.

So my question:
is their a possibility to generalize the predicate `succ` predicate in such a way, the function test would be possible. Means `succ(X,Y)` would give `Y = X + 1` and Y is calculated recursively after `N = M` is called in `test(3, N, M)`.

Comment: Swap the order of the succ and test constraints, so that the recursion unravels after test(3, N, N) has been hit, so that succ/2 has the necessary at least 1 of its 2 arguments instantiated.

Comment: Thanks, it solves the problem. In my original code its not as easy possible to swap test and succ. Is their no alternative of succ, which is able to handle with two variables and solve the problem later on after one of the variable is defined?

Comment: As the next level: clpfd (subsequently renamed to clpz): https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/clpz